# how much time a look up take in an object?

Tags: javascript

I have an object,

```
obj = {};
```

now I am adding items into this object as,

```
obj[element] = /*something*/
```

now if I want to access this object for key = element as,

```
obj[element];
```

what would be time complexity of this operation.

And please dont suggest using of Array instead of Object, I know array has constant time look up because I am adding elements at random numbers (using them as index), so if Ii use array, I will have a sparse array and that would be inefficient in terms of memory.

Comment: What kind of answer do you want, given that there are different engines and CPU ? The best we can tell is that it's very fast and one of the most optimized operations in modern engines.

Comment: It's basically a hash/associative array/map/dictionary. What do you think?

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) or [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) could probably help you.

Comment: @dystro i want to know if this operation take constant time or O(n) ??

Comment: @schnill Performance depends a lot on the javascript engine as well. Why not just test it?

Comment: @schnill "it depends". See https://developers.google.com/v8/design. But knowing if it's `O(n)` is interesting for school but not so much for real programming where you usually worry about speed even with small n.

Comment: Time complexity is really useless here, O(1) can mean hundreds of instructions if we are talking about hash table
or it can mean 1 instruction if we are talking about array access O(1)....

Answer (score 1):

It is minimal enough for you to not worry about it. Objects are a core part of javascript, and micro-optimization is bad.

You're much better off writing understandable code (whether it's with objects or what-not) than writing code that saves you `0.000000000001` seconds.

Comment: This should have been a comment, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to know: Array is an Object too in JavaScript.

Also to check speed of any operation you can do something like:

```
var obj = {}, element = "test";
obj[element] = 333333;

var time1 = new Date().getTime();       // start timestamp
for (var i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
  // here can be any code for measurement
  var a = obj[element];
}
var time2 = new Date().getTime();       // end timestamp
var result = (time2 - time1) / 1000;    // divide all time to number of iterations
alert(result + " ms");
```